# Populate control after selectedindexchange event has fired

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, devexpress

I have a MVVM WPF project where I have an devexpress accordian control which is populated with xml template items from a ViewModel. That works great, but my problem is when I click on one of the items in the accordian control and the selectedIndexChanged event is fired. I want to handle that in the MVVM manner and get the selected items value(which is a path to an xml file) from the accordian control, fetch the content of the xml file and databind a textbox control with the content of the xml file. The following is what I have tried so far.

Here is my xaml user control

```
<dxa:AccordionControl Grid.Column="0" x:Name="accordianTemplateMenu" 
SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="SubItemOrRootItem" ItemsSource="
{Binding TemplateItems}"
  ChildrenPath="TemplateItems" DisplayMemberPath="Header >
    <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <dxmvvm:EventToCommand EventName="SelectedItemChanged" Command="
{Binding EditCommand}">
            <dxmvvm:EventToCommand.EventArgsConverter>
                <Common:AccordionEventArgsConverter/>
            </dxmvvm:EventToCommand.EventArgsConverter>
        </dxmvvm:EventToCommand>
    </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
</dxa:AccordionControl>

<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" />

<TextBlock Grid.Column="2" x:Name="templateItemContainer">
    <Run Name="run" Text="{Binding XML}" ></Run>
</TextBlock>
```

This boils down to the `AccordionEventArgsConverter` which gets me the event arguments from the selecteditem in the accordian control:

```
public class AccordionEventArgsConverter : 
EventArgsConverterBase<AccordionSelectedItemChangedEventArgs>
{
    protected override object Convert(object sender, 
AccordionSelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args != null)
        {
            return args;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And finally my viewmodel:

```
class TemplateMenuViewModel
{
    private List<TemplateItem> _templateItems;

    public TemplateMenuViewModel()
    {
        EditCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(Edit, CanEdit);
    }

    public List<TemplateItem> TemplateItems
    {
        get
        {
            TemplateProvider provider = new TemplateProvider();
            return provider.GetTemplateMenuItems("pathToMenuItems");
        }
        set { _templateItems = value; }
    }

    public ICommand<object> EditCommand { get; private set; }

    public void Edit(object accordianItemArgs)
    {

    }

    public bool CanEdit(object accordianItemArgs)
    {
        return accordianItemArgs != null;
    }
}
```

I am able to get into the `public void Edit` method, which is great because from there I can use the `accordianItemArgs` to get the xml content, but how do I "return"/databind the xml content to the textblock element in the xaml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things:

- You need the TemplateMenuViewModel to define an XML property. It looks like your TextBlock is already binding to it.
- Then you need your ViewModel to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. It doesn't look like you're doing that, then raise a property changed event when the XML text is set.
- You should set your `Text="{Binding XML}"` with a Mode of OneWay:

  Text="{Binding XML, Mode=OneWay}"

If you need more information on how to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, check out this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/mvvm_first_application.htm.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help, it worked when I implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and triggered OnPropertyChanged("Xml") in the Edit method :)

Comment: OnPropertyChanged should be called in the XML property setter, not the Edit method. If there are other ways that the XML property can change, it's safer to fire the event in the property setter.